# Delphi : How to work with two Forms

Tags: forms, delphi, variables, object, delphi-7

In my Delphi program I need two Forms. One with main program and one with settings for first Form. In the Settings Form I need to rewrite variables from Main Form and in Main Form I need to know values of variables and objects (like Buttons, RadioBoxes, CheckBoxes) from Settings Form. How can I declare both of Forms?

Comment: For all information that is shared between the two forms, create a record type holding the data. Populate the record in the main form and pass in via a setting form metod or property before calling showmodal of the settings form. The setting method/property populates the setting form with the record values. If modalresult is ok in the setting form OnClose event, put the resulting values back into the record. The record can now be accessed from the main form before the settings form is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare units after keyword  "implementation"

For example

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses Classes, Forms ...;

type
  TForm1=class(TForm)
  .....
  end;

  implementation
  uses Unit2;

  TForm1.Method;
  begin
    Form2.value := something; 
  end;
```

in second unit

```
unit Unit2;
interface
uses Classes, Forms ...;

type
  TForm2=class(TForm)
  .....
  end;

  implementation
  uses Unit1;

  TForm2.Method;
  begin
    Form1.value := something; 
  end;
```

Comment: This is totally wrong. By hard-coding the specific variable `Form2` in the methods of `TForm1`, and the specific variable `Form1`  in `TForm2`, you make it impossible for either of them to be used from any other form or location in your code. Never bind class methods to specific global variables. The question I linked as a duplicate has a much better solution to the problem than this one.

Comment: Of course but question was on very basic level so in answer is also basic solution. I working on big projects so I know that such solution cant be used in such case.

Comment: Sorry, but a poor solution isn't an answer just because it's the easy way. This answer is simply wrong. The only reason I haven't downvoted it yet is because you're new here, and I was trying to be nice. :-)

Comment: I understand  you in one hundred percent! I don't know if this is good place to discuss. Of course on this subject probably one can write a book. Don't you thing that it is bather to understand programming on simple examples first? Any way thank you for your advise. It is true I am new on stackoverflow. But I programming in Delphi and not only Delphi from 18 years :-).